# java.lang.method inside @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(ABC,Def)") and revoke the current user authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-el

Need to extract the java.lang.Method and it's annotation (easy after I have the method) of an annotated method to let the current user access that method or not.

I have the following RestController:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("hello")
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(this, principal)")  // 'this' return the class, not the method. 'principal' the jwt token
    public String hello1() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

And a PermissionEvaluator implementation

```
public class PermissionEvaluatorImpl implements PermissionEvaluator {
    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth, Object targetObject, Object permission) {
        return something;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth, Serializable targuetID, String type, Object permission) {
        return something;
    }
}
```

How can I make that one of this methods receive the java.lang.method object, something like this:

```
Method method = ((Method) someAttribute);  // like this
Method method = ((Method) someAttribute.getSomething().getSomething().getSomething().getMethod());  // or like this
```

*Edit:*
Need a java.lang.method instante inside the `PermissionEvaluator` to extract the signature, parameters and the others method's annotation, in orden to generalize the `PermissionEvaluator` as much as possible, and let the responsability of evaluate the permission according to the metainfo of the method annotated with `@PreAuthorize` to another class.

*Note:*

- I'm using OAuth2 (don't know if it's relevant)
- `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()` (All request need authentication)
- Always calling the verification before the method execute (`@PreAuthorize`), if the user don't have access, the method can't execute

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. For example, why do you need Java `Method` instances? It would be great if you could post a minimal project reproducing your problem, called an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please read!) on GitHub and link to it from here. It would be much easier to help you then. The question already got a close vote (not mine), so please try to improve it. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I am starting in this world and it is comfortable to know that there is someone willing to help, so thank you. Returning to problem, I need the method instance to be able to extract information such as the name, the parameters and maybe other annotations, in order to generalize the permission evaluator

Comment: Like I said, an MCVE on GitHub would help. I am an AOP expert, not a Spring user. I know some Spring AOP, but zero Spring security. I do know that you can get the information you need from an aspect, both Spring AOP and full AspectJ variants. But in order to understand your use case, I would like to see the full picture and understand how/where you intend to use the information you asked for. BTW, what you want to achieve might be possible by on-board Spring (security) means, someone else can maybe answer that. I am focusing on the AOP solution here.

Comment: Feedback, please.